# Jquery remote validation timeout

Tags: jquery, validation, timeout

I am trying to use jquery validation to validate some input values on the form.
On one of the form I have to make a remote call to the server to check if the required
entered value is valid or not.
So I have something like:

```
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
zip: {
  required: true,
  zip: true,
  remote: "check-zip.action"
  }
 }
});
```

Now for some very unusual testing scenario - I need to handle the validation, when a server does not respond to the remote call. I see through a javascript plugin (google pagespeed)... that the remote call to the server for validation keeps on hanging out... even if the server is down. I am having hard time figuring out if there is a timeout or something I could use so that after trying to connect for desirable number of seconds.. I could call out a javascript function to display the user that ... the server was unavailable to validate the zip code.. or some other meaningful message.
i tried adding timeout:10000, but did not work..
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer... 
but I was more looking for a particular remote call during validation.

Anyways... looks like I could use

```
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
zip: {
  required: true,
  zip: true,
  remote: 
  {
   url:"check-zip.action",
   timeout:2000,
   error:handleerror
  }
 }
 }
});
```

and this will call the js function handleerror(request,error)
if the ajax call times out, or that the server is not available, depending on what comes back in the request parameter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with callbacks.

Here is the sample:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'ajax/test.html',
 success: function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
   alert('Load was performed.');
 },
 error: function(obj, errorText, exception){
   alert('Error: ' + errorText);
 }
});
```